# Book about a boy who was expelled from his clan when wrongfully accused of maiming the chief's son

Tags: story-identification, books

The book was about a boy who was expelled from his clan because he was wrongfully accused of maiming the chief's son. Does anyone know the title of this book? He then joins a group of mages (Seven of them, I think), and takes on the title of "The Wanderer" at the end of the book.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.

Comment: And don't forget to indicate what you feel makes this fantasy or sci-fi.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The mages does, doesn't it?

Comment: @edlothiad . I missed the mages. If they're the magic sort, and not just write men.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I think in this case I'd give it the benefit of the doubt